# How to solve knockout applyBindingsToNode adding multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to use knockout applyBindingsToNode to dynamically add and remove elements. The reason is I need to update my html so the binding will be cut that's why I need to use applyBindingsToNode.

I have an example here if you click on the button Rebind name, it will add four elements but I only expect 2. Anything I miss?

Here's my jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/noppanit/dhztqgbz/

```
var Model = function Model() {
    var people = ko.observableArray([{
        name: 'name1'
    }, {
        name: 'name2'
    }]);

    var changeElement = function () {
        people.push({
            name: 'name3'
        });
    };

    var rebindElement = function () {
        var peopleList = document.getElementById('people_list');
        ko.cleanNode(peopleList);

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(peopleList, {
            foreach: [{
                name: 'name3'
            }, {
                name: 'name4'
            }]
        });
    };

    return {
        people: people,
        changeElement: changeElement,
        rebindElement: rebindElement
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new Model(), document.getElementById('wrapper'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update the array only and it will update the corresponding html element.
I will update the html without rebinding.

please take a look on the following link , it is the same case

http://www.jefclaes.be/2014/04/rebinding-knockout-viewmodel.html

Comment: I updated my jsfiddle with the suggestion, but it's still not working. http://jsfiddle.net/noppanit/dhztqgbz/1/